# Layout with varying image dimensions and that maintains the aspect ratio of the image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

[Here is the apple example, how do they change the size of the image, place it in the layout that is changing row by row and still maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oARMX.jpg)

Comment: They are not changing the size of the image just the size of the cell used in the layout.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, i was wondering what is the size of cell based on, how does it preserve the clarity of the photo without varying the height in the row.

Comment: Probably the width of the device to fit a portrait image and landscape and have the proper spacing in between and left and right. This would probably then set the height. Just guessing but that is how I would do the math